# Images get corrupted when uploaded

Tags: images, whatsapp

When I try to upload an image, a weird corrupted version gets uploaded instead.
This happens on different platforms, sometimes on google images (searching by file), But consistently happens when I send image on Whatsapp Web.

I have a dual-boot with linux and Windows 10, and the same thing happens there.

[This is the image that gets uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SejPF.jpg)

Each time there's a slightly different, random pattern and colors.

I have tried reinstall the graphics driver.

Edit 1:
The image uploaded to whatsapp is the corrupted version,
So whoever got the message will see the corrupted version.
The same goes for if I try to view it through my whatsapp on my phone.

Comment: Check the WhatsApp chat on your phone. Does the picture appear corrupted there?

Comment: Yes, it's also corrupted on the phone's whatsapp chat.